# Apply a property to a class but not to its :before and :after

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a stepper in the form of arrow (using angular / css mostly). Let's start with this [codepen](https://codepen.io/keithra/pen/wrmVwY). What I want to do now, is to center the status name **in the middle** of the arrow.

The straight-forward idea I had was to do something *around those lines* to apply the text-align center property.

```
.block-head {
   /* rest of the class css */
   text-align: center;
}

.block-head:before {
   /* rest of the class css */
   text-align: left;
}

.block-head:after {
   /* rest of the class css */
   text-align: left;
}
```

Problem is this is **not** working. I tried setting the text align property to center on the block-text class aswell, but it's not working either...

How can I apply the text-align:center property to my class but not to it's :before & :after ? And if it's not possible, how should I change my code to keep the current design and have the text centered ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` properties for this.

Add `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center` to `block-text`

[codepen](https://codepen.io/solbreslin/pen/KXRXxv)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways are there to get it . Try like this. This is a quick fix by giving your `.block-text` `margin-left:50%;`

```js
function ctrl($scope){
  
  // those variable are passed as param to the directive
  $scope.selectedKey = 2
  $scope.elements =
            [
              {
                name: "Status 1",
                key: 1,
                description: "description status 1"
              },
              {
                name: "Status 2",
                key: 2,
                description: "description status 2"
              },
              {
                name: "Status 3",
                key: 3,
                description: "description status 3"
              },
              {
                name: "Status 4",
                key: 4,
                description: "description status 4"
              }
            ]

            $scope.colors =
            {
                current: "lightblue",
                success: "lightgreen",
                disable: "lightgrey"
            }
  
  
  
  
   $scope.widthCalc = ($scope.elements.length - 1) * 26
   $scope.getColor = function($index) {
            if ($scope.elements[$index].key === $scope.selectedKey)
              return $scope.colors['current']
            if ($scope.elements[$index].key < $scope.selectedKey)
              return $scope.colors['success']
            if ($scope.elements[$index].key > $scope.selectedKey)
              return $scope.colors['disable']
          }
  
}
```

```css
.block-container {
 width: auto;
 padding-top: 4px;
 padding-right: 8px;
 padding-left: 8px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.block-head {
  background-color: #4D81BF;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
 width:22px;
  margin-right:4px;
 margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.block-text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
 margin-left: 50%;
}

.block-head:before {
  color: #FAFAFA;
  border-left: 10px solid;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
 z-index:1;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
}

.block-head:after {
  color: inherit;
 z-index:2;
  border-left: 10px solid;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top:0;
}

.block-head-first {
  margin-left:0px !important;
}

.block-head-last {
  margin-right:0px;
}

.block-head-first:before {
  color: #FAFAFA;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
 z-index:1;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
}

.block-head-last:after {
  color: #4D81BF;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
 z-index:1;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Angular JS Demo</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="block-container">
  <div ng-repeat="element in elements"
  class="block-head"
  ng-class="{'block-head-first': $first, 'block-head-last': $last}"
  ng-style="{'width' : selectedKey === element.key ? 'calc(100% - ' + widthCalc + 'px)' : '',
             'background-color': getColor($index),
             'color': getColor($index)}">
    <span class="block-text" ng-if="selectedKey === element.key">{{element.name}}</span>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This would be awkwardly centered though, but it's close to what i wanted. @ovokuro found the solution I was looking for

Comment: As I mentioned it can be done in multiple ways, even using position also you can do the same, so as for flex. Flex supports are limited to IE. So you can choose based on your requirement. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
.block-head {
   text-align: center;
}

.block-head:before {
   left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my [codepen:](https://codepen.io/intervalia/pen/MOyKYd).

The fix was relatively simple.
You were trying to change the `text-align` of the outer element and I changed it for the inner element:

```
block-text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I also changed from `margin-left` to `padding-left` to properly handle the `width: 100%`